# How to callback on certain text

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to find a reliable way to perform a callback when certain text is typed into the editor. I want to run certain code when an @ is typed (to then allow a selection of user's to link to).

Currently I am doing it by using the "change" event and then trying to look back at what is before the current selection:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'ipsmentions', {
    init: function( editor ) {

        /* When the content of the editor is changed, check if it was an @ */
        editor.on( 'change', function(e) {
            /* If we currently have just normal text selected, we're typing normally and there might be an @ */
            var selection = editor.getSelection();
            if ( selection.getType() == CKEDITOR.SELECTION_TEXT ) {
                /* Loop the ranges... */
                var ranges = selection.getRanges( true );
                for ( var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++ ) {
                    /* If the start container and end container are the same (meaning we just have a normal caret, indicating normal typing, nothing highlighted) and that is a text node... */
                    if ( ranges[i].startContainer.equals( ranges[i].endContainer ) && ranges[i].endContainer instanceof CKEDITOR.dom.text ) {
                        if ( ranges[i].startContainer.getText().substr( ranges[i].startOffset - 1, 1 ) == '@' ) {
                            console.log('@ pressed!');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
});
```

But I'm guessing this isn't the best way. In particular, I notice that if I type @ and then hit enter (to start a new paragraph) I get "@ pressed" in the console again.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asynchronous check should help with enter key. I would also use some backwards [`range.cloneContents`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range-method-cloneContents) because you never know in what type of node the selection might be anchored. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oleq/kf9ge2gk/).

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    on: {
        change: function() {
            CKEDITOR.tools.setTimeout( function() {
                var sel = this.getSelection(),
                    range = sel.getRanges()[ 0 ];

                if ( !range.collapsed ) {
                    console.warn( 'non–collapsed range' );
                    return;
                }

                if ( !range.startOffset ) {
                    console.warn( 'at the beginning of the node' );
                    return;
                }

                range.setStart( range.startContainer, 0 );

                if ( range.cloneContents().$.textContent.substr( -1 ) == '@' ) {
                    console.log( '@ inserted' );
                }                
            }, 0, this );
        }
    }
} );
```